# Is there a way I could make character movement adjust to camera rotation in UPBGE?

Tags: game-engine

Logic Node Editor

I'm trying to make a fps character but I have no idea how to make the character move in the rotation of the camera.

if you still don't understand. If I was to look forward and press W I would go forward but if I was to look right and press W it would move left